# Receiving and processing 3rd party Posts in Tapestry app

Tags: java, post, request, tapestry, hipchat

The goal of my app is to create a leaderboard for a competition.  To add to one's score, you just have to write something in hipchat (I already have a listener in hipchat that attempts to make a post to my Tapestry app).

I am running into lots of trouble around accepting and handling a 3rd party POST to my Tapestry app.  All the documentation I can find deals with internal requests.

Does anyone have any experience in setting up a way to receive a 3rd party post, handle it and make actions with the information?  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tapestry's native POST handling is intended for handling HTML form submits and is not a good match for machine initiated REST requests. Consequently, I'd handle it as a REST resource request, which [JAX-WS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Web_Services) is meant for. I assume you mean Tapestry 5 and if so, it's pretty to get started with [Tynamo's tapestry-resteasy module](http://www.tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide/) (for disclosure, I'm one of the maintainers). If you are new to JAX-WS, you may want to [read an overview about it](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/Jersey/Overview+of+JAX-RS+1.0+Features) (the link is for Jersey, the reference implementation but the annotations work the same way regardless of implementation). In principle, you'd implement a (POJO+annotations) resource class and an operation with something like this:

```
@POST
@Produces({"application/json"})
public Response scorePoints(User user, long score)
{
    leaderboardService.add(user, score);
    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

On the client side, you'd just pass in the user ID and Tapestry's type coercion would handle the rest (assuming User is a known entity to Tapestry). Of course, you could just use primitive data types on both sides as well.

Comment: Kalle, thanks so much for the answer.  In the meantime, I decided to just pass the information via URL parameters.  This app doesn't really have security requirements so that method was extremely simple compared to the alternatives.